# Execute browser as root

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, root, browser, hosts

I need to run my browser as root, in order to gain [Citrix receiver](http://www.citrix.com/go/receiver.html), which is executed within the browser, permissions to access and edit the `hosts` file.

Otherwise I get this error:

> You do not have permission to change hosts file. Please verify that
>   you have write permissions in the /etc directory.

Apparently Citrix needs access to `hosts` and the only way, I know of, is executing Firefox as root by:

```
sudo firefox
```

Are there any security issues when executing the browser as root?

Is there any way to make the `hosts` file permanently editable, so that I don't have to execute Firefox as root?

### Update 1

As suggested by mikeserv, I executed

```
cp /etc/hosts /tmp
sudo unshare -m sh -c '
    mount -B /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
    exec runuser -u '"$USER"' firefox'
```

In the newly opened instance of firefox I tried to access my ressources with Citrix, but got the same error as above.
Besides, I got the following error dump in the terminal:

```
1449062781808   addons.xpi  WARN    Can't iterate directory /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/2vytc6tm.default/extensions: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFile.directoryEntries]"  nsresult: "0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: getDirectoryEntries :: line 1713"  data: no] Stack trace: getDirectoryEntries()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1713 < DirInstallLocation__readAddons()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:7502 < DirectoryInstallLocation()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:7441 < addDirectoryInstallLocation()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2298 < XPI_startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2347 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:221 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:828 < AMI_startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:999 < AMP_startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:2672 < AMC_observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:58 < <file:unknown>

(firefox:7994): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-9dyvIdS0jP: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt

(firefox:7994): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-CBkXMgnC2r: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt

(firefox:7994): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Verbindung ist gescheitert: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt

(firefox:7994): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/user/.cache/dconf/user': Keine Berechtigung.  dconf will not work properly.

(firefox:7994): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/user/.cache/dconf/user': Keine Berechtigung.  dconf will not work properly.

...

(firefox:7994): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-dMG4PGVMeg: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt

(firefox:7994): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/user/.cache/dconf/user': Keine Berechtigung.  dconf will not work properly.

(firefox:7994): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-jIIyll6Cjh: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt

...
```

### Update 2

```
JVMLauncher.afterStart(): starting JVM process watcher

(wfica:4510): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 75 was not found when attempting to remove it

(wfica:4510): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 127 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Comment: Changing perms on `/etc/hosts` is not a good idea. If any software asks for your browser to be run as root it has serious design issues, IMHO.

Comment: @schaiba: It doesn't explicitly ask to run my browser as root, but it needs full acces to `hosts` and, afaik, it's the only way to gain those rights.

Comment: Can you link us to a page where it says that it needs r/w access to `/etc/hosts` ? I can't seem to find it myself.

Comment: @schaiba: I couldn't find a suitable link, but when trying to run it as normal user I get an error message, saying that it has no access to `hosts`. I tested in on several systems (Windows 7,8,10) and now on Ubuntu.

Comment: `hosts` or `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: @schaiba: Apparently it's `/etc/hosts`. Please see my update.

Comment: you can privately bind mount another file over it/

Comment: It's not very helpful to say that it should not have to do that... if you *need* to run it though use acls to modify /etc/hosts (setfacl -m u:user:rw /etc/hosts) and check what changes it does. Remove acls later.

Comment: @nkms I think you're in error to say that software might have a legitimate reason to write /etc/hosts. (no user-level software really ever should)  On the other hand, the ACL recommendation mostly constitutes an answer if you'd turn it into one.

Comment: -1 to the question, not because it is poorly researched, but because you're asking how to do something very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set write permissions to `/etc/hosts` because you are in risk that an attacker redirects your traffic to the website which is under control and thus perform nefarious actions such as [drive-by download attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download) that could lead to installing malware on your computer without your consent by crafting a malicious JavaScript code that could exploit the vulnerabilities of your Firefox browser or one of its plugins/extensions. The same file on Windows OS is targeted by malware authors to spread trojans. Only you the owner must have the right to write it.

Comment: So executing firefox as root would be a less risky solution in my case?

Comment: See @mikeserv's solution above. Running a browser as root is a faux pas except for out-of-the-ordinary cases and/or testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

with a linux `mount` namespace you can get close to the same effect but with substantially less liability.

```sh
cp /etc/hosts /tmp
sudo -E unshare -m sh -c '
    mount -B /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
    runuser -p '"$USER"' -c firefox'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't work. Please see my update.

Comment: @user1170330 - yeah - its probably environment stuff. a little testing and i made it work for me... see the edit.

Comment: This time a get another error, please see Update 2.

Comment: @user1170330 - look this a possible solution. i cant possibly know what all of that stuff is - i dont have a clear understanding of why the programs you want to run require you to lower your defenses. but all i offered you was a solution which might allow you to lower them *less*. otherwise, given a problem like this, you need to sort it out with the *vendor*.

Comment: @user1170330 I must agree with mikeserv.  If the vendor of the browser demands reduced security, then the vendor cannot be trusted.  If I were to run such a thing (unlikely) It would be run on independent hardware that other hardware ignores because it is just not credible.